# How do I forward fill on specific rows only in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ffill

I have the following df:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    a   1.0   1.0
1    b   NaN   NaN   
2    c   5.0   3.0
3    d   5.0   NaN
```

I want to do forward fill the rows only where col2 = NaN so the result would be like this

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    a   1.0   1.0
1    b   1.0   1.0   
2    c   5.0   3.0
3    d   5.0   NaN
```

I was able to get to here but this isn't a smart solution because it ffills row 3 even though it doesn't meet the requirements of `col2 = NaN`

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(method="ffill")
df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna(method="ffill")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
df.fillna(df.ffill().where(df['col2'].isna()))
```

output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       1.0     1.0
1   b       1.0     1.0
2   c       5.0     3.0
3   d       5.0     NaN
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col2': [1, None, 5, 5], 'col3': [1, None, 3, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for in place filling:

```
df.loc[df['col2'].isna()] = df.ffill()
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    a   1.0   1.0
1    b   1.0   1.0
2    c   5.0   3.0
3    d   5.0   NaN
```